# Flutter FFmpeg - [AVFilterGraph @ 0x88f4b300] No such filter: '"scale'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

So, I am trying to combine an image and an audio file and convert it to a video using ffmpeg in flutter using flutter-ffmpeg but I am getting this error when I am trying to use executewithareguments() function.
[image]

I am getting this error ->
[image]

I suspected that maybe I should remove the double quotes but even that is giving an error. It would be very helpful if someone tells me what I am doing wrong.
Also, I was using min-gpl version of ffmpeg, I thought that was causing the problem, so I changed it to full-gpl but the error still remains. Any form of help would be great.

Comment: Can you show the final command that is executed?

Comment: The double quotes are interpreted as part of the filter name: `'"scale'`. What happens when you remove them?

Comment: @Gyan I was still getting an error that '(' is unrecognised.

Comment: @Csisanyi I have already posted the command that I am trying to execute, see the 1st screenshot, command to execute.

Comment: I see that, but how does this look on a command line?

Comment: Might be a very trivial syntax error, but I’m not familiar with this ffmpwg lib. It would be great to see what comman is executed.

Comment: @Csisanyi, that is the command and to execute it I use the command <FlutterFFmpegObject>.executeWithCommand(command). I have used the same syntax on my pc to check if it was correct and there it ran just fine.

Comment: Ok, got it.
If you remove the double quotes, do you get the same error?

Comment: yes i get the error '(' unrecognised. @Csisanyi

Comment: I'm getting invalid size error when using your 2*trunc(ih/2) value. Are you sure this scale attribute is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
val cmd = arrayOf("-i",
            inputVideoPath,
            "-i",
            inputVideo2Path,
            "-y",
            "-filter_complex",
            "[1]scale=${1200}:${800}[b];[0][b] overlay=${imageXPosition}:${imageYPosition}",
             "-pix_fmt",
            "yuv420p",
            "-c:a",
            "copy",
            "-preset",
            "ultrafast",
            outputVideoPath)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).